# Is Socket.BeginReceive(IList<ArraySegment<byte>> buffers.. Not Asynchronous?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, ilist, buffering, beginreceive

I have been looking to implement a custom class of :

```
IList<ArraySegment<byte>>
```

this will be passed to a socket, and used as the buffer to receive data from that Socket.

```
Socket.BeginReceive(
    IList<ArraySegment<Byte>>, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object
    )
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sah14d0.aspx)

While testing I have found that when calling

BeginReceive(IList..

It blocks?!  When replacing this with the BeginReceive(byte[]... is acts asynchronously.

**Has anyone else come accross this?**

I will post my testing code up if required but would like to hear from anyone out there before I uglify this question :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So! I found out the issue.

As I had a

```
Console.WriteLine
```

present in my custom

```
IList<ArraySegment<byte>>
```

then the method was not acting asynchronously on compile :)

Comment: What are the odds Chris :)